# List collection where case too slow for 30000 items

Tags: c#, list

I use a list collection which it holds two items ID and Barcode. The list contains about 30000 rows.

When is use the code below is takes about 600ms. Is there any way I can make it a little faster?

```
var InventoryItemID = mBarcode.Where(x => (x.Barcode == Barcode.Text))
                              .Select(x => x.InventoryItemID)
                              .First();
```

Comment: `mBarcode` is a `List`?

Comment: Yes it is a list collection with id and Barocde. ID is int and Barcode is String

Comment: 600ms sounds quite slow for only 30000 rows. Are you running in debug mode? You could try caching the `Barcode.Text` value into a local variable, to see if this will make any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a `Dictionary<K,V>` keyed on `Barcode` with `InventoryItems` as values.

I can't see your classes to be exact, but something like this:

```
class Barcode
{
    public string BarcodeText { get; set; }
    public int InventoryItemId { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create some  barcodes
        Barcode bc1 = new Barcode { BarcodeText = "AAA", InventoryItemId = 123 };
        Barcode bc2 = new Barcode { BarcodeText = "BBB", InventoryItemId = 456 };
        Barcode bc3 = new Barcode { BarcodeText = "CCC", InventoryItemId = 789 };

        Dictionary<string, Barcode> dict = new Dictionary<string, Barcode>();

        // Add to dictionary, keying on the barcode's text
        dict.Add(bc1.BarcodeText, bc1);
        dict.Add(bc2.BarcodeText, bc2);
        dict.Add(bc3.BarcodeText, bc3);

        // Lookup on the barcode text and get the required property
        Console.WriteLine(dict["BBB"].InventoryItemId);
    }
}
```

For large numbers, this will be faster, because searching on the List is linear, so average search time is proportional the number of items (N).

A dictionary does a partitioned search on the hash value of the key, and is proportional to the binary log of N.

Comment: Thank you what is dictionary can you give me an example? Also it is better to read from a database instead a list collection for so many rows?

Comment: @ΔημήτρηςΧριστοφορίδης See [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue> Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: I've added more detail.

Comment: Thank you your solution works fine. Please explain me if it is better to use a list collection or a database instead this. Has to do with the number of row?

Comment: No simple answer as to whether a database would be better. If you have 30,000 items, they clearly have to be stored somewhere - either a file or a database.

If the 30,000 fit into your program's memory all at the same time, then searching in memory will probably be quicker, but the load of 30,000 may be slow. Thus if you load once and search many times, you should be okay. But if you load before each search, it will be slow.

If you have more items than can fit in the program's memory, then you'll have to search in the database. Probably quicker than the list but not the dictionary.